# What is `ff.im`?

Tags: redirect, dns, mapping

When we visit `fm.im`, we are redirected to http://friendfeed.com.

Here are some other examples:

1. `ff.im/abc`
2. `ff.im/efg`

How is FriendFeed able to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.im is the [Isle of Man](https://www.nic.im/home.mth) top-level domain ([ccTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain)). The registry normally requires names to be at least three characters long, unless you pay [considerably more](https://www.nic.im/public/pricing.mth).

Two-character domains look cool but aren't particularly useful since IE [rejects their cookies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310676) (old article, but still mostly true for newer IE versions).

When your browser requests `ff.im`:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
host: ff.im
```

their webserver responds with a redirect, either to the main FriendFeed site:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 09 Apr 2011 12:29:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://friendfeed.com/
Server: FriendFeedServer/0.1
```

or to some other place (when using their URL-shortener).

Comment: Thanks for the info, Btw are you aware of free domains besides the ones provided by tokelau (dot.tk) ?